# What's the difference between dict(d) and d.copy() in python2.7 dict

Tags: python, dictionary, copy

Below is the code:

```
import timeit
d = {1:2}
print min(timeit.repeat(lambda: dict(d)))
print min(timeit.repeat(lambda: d.copy()))
```

Below is the output:

```
0.360497951508
0.208737850189
```

I just want to know what's the difference between dict(d) and d.copy()? I know both of them are shallow copy.

Comment: This blog post provides a thorough description of what `dict(d)` does: https://doughellmann.com/blog/2012/11/12/the-performance-impact-of-using-dict-instead-of-in-cpython-2-7-2/